# Updating MongoDB collection record - NodeJS Express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, cron, ejs

### Objective

I have a program the sends data to the `MongoDb` collection. This data is supposed to add 5 different data with different `title` tags into the same record.
What I want to do is when another record is entered by the user, **this program will match `title tags` of the existing records with the new one entered by the user, if it exists it will overwrite it entirely.** Then, these collection records will go into my program and **run one by one (individual records)**.

#### My POST ROUTE

If the `title: "example"` **already exists in the collection it will overwrite the `title,password,tags,actions` again. There is no update button, just the button to add in my EJS.**

```
control.post('/like/:id',getuserdata, async (req, res, next) => {
    try{
        var likechar = new likeSch({
            title: res.accountuser.title, //This title here will be the identifier for the program.
            password: res.accountuser.password,
            tags: req.body.likes,
            actions: req.body.action,
        });
        likechar.save().then(function(){
            assert(likechar.isNew === false)
            next();
        });
        res.redirect('/like')
        } catch (err){
            console.log(err)
        }
});
```

Thank you! And please comment for any clarification!